# Angularjs: date compare with current date in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to separate data if date is less then current date or equal or greater that current date. date should not include time.
My code is

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="val in x">
    {{val.dt}}
    <div ng-if="date > val.dt ">Past</div>
    <div ng-if="date < val.dt">Future</div>
    <div ng-if="date = val.dt ">Present</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and angularjs controller is

```
$scope.date = new Date();
$scope.x = [{dt:"2018-07-12"},{dt:"2018-07-14"},{dt:"2018-07-10"}];
```

But it's not working as i want. it gives me output

```
2018-07-12
Past
Future
Present
2018-07-14
Past
Future
Present
2018-07-10
Past
Future
Present
```

but i want output if current date is 2018-07-12

```
2018-07-12
Present
2018-07-14
Future
2018-07-10
Past
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is you are comparing a Date with a String.

Your `date` variable is type Date, and your `x` array data is String.

For simplicity, and only if your format is YYYY-MM-DD, I would recomend you to format your `date`var into text:

```
var d= new Date();
$scope.date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2)
$scope.x = [{dt:"2018-07-12"},{dt:"2018-07-14"},{dt:"2018-07-10"}];
```

In angular 1.0.x:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="val in x">
{{val.dt}}

  <div ng-show="date > val.dt">
   - Past
  </div>
  <div ng-show="date < val.dt">
   - Future
  </div>
  <div ng-show="date == val.dt">
   - Present
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried what you give. but still not working my fiddle line is with your coed http://jsfiddle.net/RyW9m/3065/

Comment: Your fiddle is Angular 1.0... replage ng-if with ng-show

Comment: ng-show working for me but only ng-if working can't display date with {{val.dt}}

Comment: Thanks bro. Your code working for me after some small changes. updated fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RyW9m/3081/

Comment: Ok!! That sounds good. If my answer was helpful I would appreciate your vote ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <div ng-repeat="val in x">
      {{val.dt}}
      <div ng-if="date.getTime() > getTimestamp(val.dt)">Past</div>
      <div ng-if="date.getTime() < getTimestamp(val.dt)">Future</div>
      <div ng-if="date.getTime() == getTimestamp(val.dt)">Present</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

AngularJs:

```
$scope.getTimestamp = function(dateTime) {
   return new Date(dateTime).getTime();
}
```

Comment: I think, it is only work if time also same for current and my date. but i do not want to compare with time

Comment: Can you please give me any fiddle link for that.

Comment: Yep, I think problem come by ng-if, use ng-show it will work right.
https://jsfiddle.net/16vLjkf2/7/
Because ng-repeat can not work with ng-if to check show an element.

Comment: Past print again and again, means conditions not working properly.

Comment: sorry, My error syntax, I have updated ^^ https://jsfiddle.net/blakenguyen/16vLjkf2/11/